# jquery error: "missing : after property id" (JavaScript object)

Tags: jquery, exception

I have this code:

```
$.each(properties, function(i, key) {
   obj.css({'-webkit-border-' + key + '-radius': value+'px', '-moz-border-' + key + '-radius': value+'px', 'border-' + key + '-radius': value+'px'});
});
```

It's giving the error on the first + key

Can't I create keys like this (with appending data) or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't I create keys like this (with appending data) or am I doing something else wrong?

Nope, you should be getting a syntax error.

You can construct the object before passing it to the `css` function:

```
var styles = {};
styles['-webkit-border-' + key + '-radius'] = value+'px';
styles['-moz-border-' + key + '-radius'] = value+'px';
styles['border-' + key + '-radius'] = value+'px';
obj.css(styles);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, though I now have another error to fix ;) (somewhere else)

Comment: +1 The property must be *"either a name, a number, or a string literal"* - [See reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers)

Comment: Can you look at the edits I made to the question, it seems the dynamically generated a, b, c don't work for some reason with .css()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.each(properties, function(i, key) {
   var a = '-webkit-border-' + key + '-radius';
   var b = '-moz-border-' + key + '-radius';
   var c = 'border-' + key + '-radius';
   var z = value+'px';
   obj.css({a : z, b: z, c: z});
});
```

I think that json don't like "building" its keys and values directly

Comment: Actually, there is no JSON involved anywhere on this question :)